# Intellij does not recognize lombok.config when building

Tags: intellij-lombok-plugin

I opened the restbucks project with Intellij. I have lombok plugin installed, annotation processing enabled. I am using javac compiler in Intellij settings. I have lombok.config in project root like in git repository, I also tried copying it to src/main/java and src/main/resources but no matter what I try, when I build the project with Intellij, after posting an order, I get:

> Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for
>   org.springsource.restbucks.order.Order, annotations: {interface
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}]
>   has no property name annotation; must have name when
>   multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator

Seems like `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties=true` has no effect. When I build with maven then it works fine. 
When I delete the lombok.config file, Intellij starts showing errors all over the project so the file seems to be recognized by Intellij afterall. But the build doesn't run as expected as posting to orders fails as mentioned above. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Lombok plugin does support `lombok.config` file.

The `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties` is deprecated as per in Lombok [doc](https://projectlombok.org/changelog)

> BREAKING CHANGE: lombok config key lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties is now deprecated and defaults to true, that is, by default lombok no longer automatically generates @ConstructorProperties annotations. New config key lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties now exist; set it to true if you want the old behavior. Oracle more or less broke this annotation with the release of JDK9, necessitating this breaking change.

Use the new `lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties` in the `lombok.config` located in the root folder and 
 also, perform a clean install and then should be fine.

Comment: My new lombok.config did not work until I did a `mvn clean install` as shared by @flávio-henrique

Answer (score 1):

My observation is that the `lombok.config` file has to be in `src/main/java` not `src/main/resources` for IntelliJ to pick it up.

Comment: This saved my day! Indeed I was putting it in `src/main/resources` (since it's a resource...) and it was ignored! Moving it into `src/main/java` solved the problem!